# How to add moving average to Report Builder 2.0 chart

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

This is driving me nuts.  I've looked at all the [relevant MSDN tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207034.aspx) but they talk about 'data field drop zones' and how a 'Add Calculated Series' menu option should be there but *it's not*, and no screenshot is provided to show what a 'data field drop zone' is.  This is the menu I get when I "right-click on a field in the data field drop zone":

[image: Screenshot of Report Builder 2.0]

The frustrating thing is I know I've seen this calculated series stuff before, but I can't find it again, it's not in the 'Series Properties' dialog that I can see, and I can't find a tutorial showing how to find this feature.  I'm guessing you can only have a calculated series on certain chart types, or I don't have some flag turned on or something, but I didn't see that mentioned anywhere.

Can you tell me how I can add a line showing the median of my data to a chart in Report Builder 2.0?  I think I can do this by adding a 'Moving Average' via a 'Calculated Series', but I can't find how to add that.

**Edit:**  on a different chart, the 'Add Calculated Series' menu option was available.  It was a stacked column chart and the series I right-clicked on was an expression that used `RunningValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove the series group (from the 'data field drop zone' on the right side of the chart) so that all I had was 1) a category group (bottom of the chart) and 2) a data series (top of the chart).  Then I could right-click on the data series at the top of the chart and 'Add Calculated Series' was a menu option.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by making the groups as individual series and then a combined series that i set to hidden. I was then able to make the calculated series from the hidden series.